# Create a compound condition in a Data View using the RowFilter property to equal a value entered by a null value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm pretty sure I've done confused myself by looking up everything I could on this issue but have not been able to figure what I've done wrong. 
I am thinking I've done more than one thing wrong so I could use any help you may see improvement needed in.
I am needing a user to enter their customer id on a page for a survey that will populate when submit button is clicked a list box.  The submit is supposed to retrieve the customers closed incidents only and return those only and produce a message saying that there aren't any incidents available for them to survey. I know I don't have my quotes right on the rowfilter = part so any help is greatly appreciated.
I am supposed to use a data view to filter the rows so only the closed incidents for that customer is displayed. I am supposed to set the rowfilter property to a compound condition where customerID is equal to the text box they enter and the DateClosed is not null.

```
protected void btnGetIncidents_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView IncidentsTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    IncidentsTable.RowFilter = "CustomerID = 'txtCustomerID.Text + And DateClosed is Not Null'";
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)IncidentsTable[0];

    if (IncidentsTable.Count > 0)
    {
        this.DisplayIncidents();
        this.Enable(true);
        lstIncident.Focus();
    }
}
private void DisplayIncidents()
{
    lstIncident.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select an Incident--"));
    foreach (DataRowView row in IncidentsTable)
    {
        Incident i = new Incident();
        i.IncidentID = Convert.ToInt32(row["IncidentID"]);
        i.ProductCode = row["ProductCode"].ToString();
        i.DateClosed = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateClosed"]);
        i.Title = row["Title"].ToString();
        lstIncident.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.CustomerIncidentDisplay(), i.IncidentID.ToString()));
    }
    lstIncident.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

error msg says this Message=Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String. on my rowfilter line.

Yes I know there are better ways but I am per instructions required to use this and the other elements I mention.  However, I'd love the input if you had the time to spare on what would be the better way mind you.  I've added grey hairs over this so any help and you are my hero.  Thanks.
If I need to include any other parts let me know I just didn't think it should be six miles long is all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IncidentTable.RowFilter = "CustomerID ="+txt_CustomerID.Text+ 
                          "AND DateClosed IS NOT NULL";
```

it worked for me...